# Lifetime disable of html cache block

Tags: magento-1.9, block-cache

I'm on Magento 1.9.2.2 and getting the static block bug. As a work around I disable the blocks html cache, the problem goes away.

But every day something goes in and the block html cache gets invalidated and the bug reappears. I then have to disable the block html again,  and the next day again, and the next day again.

I'm no programmer. How do I disable the cache permanently so it doesn't refresh and go into invalidate state?

I just want this bug to go a way so people can use my site.

Comment: Have you checked your blocks to insure that they are not setting a cache lifetime?

Answer (score -1):

You need to search for this block in your theme `XML`s and then

> set Cache Lifetime to 1 second

for exemple (0 or null is not allowed):

```
<block type="core/template" name="my_block" template="class/block.phtml">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>1</lifetime></action>
</block>
```

Comment: Of cousre you can et it to 0 ... plesae check linked question.